# Avoid CSRF attacks by creating form with JavaScript on CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, csrf, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

[CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) says to avoid CSRF attacks it is necessary to include the **Security** component in the controller, and in addition, create the form using the **FormHelper**.

In my case, i need to create some form fields (such as a textarea) using JavaScript (jQuery) and therefor I can not use the FormHelper for them.

```
$('#body').html('<textarea name="data[post][body]" type="textarea" cols="30" rows="3">'+text+'</textarea>');
```

And of course, it doesn't pass the security and the form fails to be submitted.

Is there anyway I can create a secure Form creating some fields with JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one option you have is to unlock these fields so they are ignored in the security check.  In your view, write:

```
<?php $this->Form->unlockField('fieldname'); ?>
```

Another option would be to create the form fields you want to add dynamically with the Form helper in a hidden area of the form and only show them if needed.

Comment: So in that case, is it the form protected even the system won't check this form?

Comment: unlocked fields are not protected and could be tampered with. For the other solution: Yes